# adding restriction to jquery datepicker on Indian holiday list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

How can I add a restriction on selecting dates as per Indian holiday list and also a restriction on choosing previous dates from now()

```
 <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 </head>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div style="height: 220px">
     <div style="height: 191px; width: 1156px">
     <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <script src="Js/JScript1.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
       <script src="Js/JScript2.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>


      <script>
        $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    </div>
   </form>
   </body>
```

i have already searched Google but could not find my answer. please help

Comment: Just a suggestion ... why not validate the date once it is selected ? if it's one of the restricted don't let the form post?

Comment: Rameez's approach is more correct.  Guide the user & validate their choice, but don't completely block their functionality.